# How check vxml has error?

Tags: xml, ivr, vxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!-- DOCTYPE vxml SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1:5000/voicexml1-0.dtd" -->
<vxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">

  <form id="dtmfForm">
      <property name="inputmodes" value="dtmf"/>
      <field name="dtmf">
        <audio src="http://localhost/File/voicefiles/T/menu/playCatDefinition.wav"/>

    <prompt>press 1</prompt>
        <audio src="http://localhost/File/voicefiles/T/cats/Love.wav"/>

    <prompt>press 2</prompt>
        <audio src="http://localhost/File/voicefiles/T/cats/Thinking of you.wav"/>

    <prompt>press 3</prompt>
        <audio src="http://localhost/File/voicefiles/T/cats/Oba Nathi Da.wav"/>

    <prompt>press 4</prompt>
        <audio src="http://localhost/File/voicefiles/T/cats/Adareta Kiyana Katha.wav"/>

    <prompt>press 5</prompt>
        <audio src="http://localhost/File/voicefiles/T/cats/Akamatththa.wav"/>

    <prompt>press 6</prompt>
        <audio src="http://localhost/File/voicefiles/T/cats/Sorry.wav"/>

    <prompt>press 7</prompt>
        <audio src="http://localhost/File/voicefiles/T/cats/Birthday.wav"/>

    <prompt>press 8</prompt>
        <audio src="http://localhost/File/voicefiles/T/cats/Annivesary.wav"/>

    <prompt>
        go to next step press 0 
    </prompt>

        <grammar mode="dtmf" root="digit">
          <rule id="digit" scope="public"> 
            <one-of>
                <item>0</item>
                <item>1</item>
                <item>2</item>
                <item>3</item>
                <item>4</item>
                <item>5</item>
                <item>6</item>
                <item>7</item>
                <item>8</item>
                <item>9</item>
            </one-of>
          </rule>
        </grammar>

    <if cond="dtmf=='9'">
        <goto next="http://localhost/myApp/resteasy/service/msisdn/7777?greetingCatagory='dtmf'"/>
    <else />
        <goto next="http://localhost/myApp/resteasy/service/msisdn/7777?greeting='dtmf'"/>
    </if>
      </field>      
    </form>
    <nomatch>
        No Match! I'm sorry, I didn't understand you.  Could you please try that again? 
        <reprompt />
    </nomatch>
    <noinput>
        No Input! I'm sorry, I didn't hear anything.  Could you please try that again? 
        <reprompt />
    </noinput>
</vxml>
```

Consider this **vxml** any error in this how to check vxml have error. How to, I Solve it? what kind error include in this vxml some time go to `<goto next={url}/>` this step other code not working .what is the error in this code? how to mange time next step go to.. I am looking for suitable answer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<goto>` element can't be inside `<field>`, that is responsible for collecting information from the user. It should be moved to `<filled>` responsible for it's interpretation. Structure is the following:

```
<form>
  <field>
    <grammar>...</grammar>
  </field>
  <filled>
     <goto ...
  </filled>
</form>
```

[Voxeo documentation - filled element](http://help.voxeo.com/go/help/xml.vxml.elements.filled)

Comment: i develop code like this but then code had error. why get error like this?

Answer (score 0):

VoiceXML document validation can be done against [VoiceXML DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/vxml.dtd), in the code you posted `<goto>` and also `<if>` elements are what in VoiceXML is called executable content, executable content can be contained only in the following elements:

- `<block>`
- `<catch>`
- `<error>`
- `<help>`
- `<noinput>`
- `<nomatch>`
- `<if>`
- `<filled>`

So in your page the `<if>` element is inside the wrong element.

Online (Voice)XML validation can be done using the [validator](https://validator.w3.org/) on the W3C site, direct validation of your document against W3C validator would give the following error:

> Line 57, Column 25: document type does not allow element "if" here;
>   missing one of "catch", "help", "noinput", "nomatch", "error",
>   "filled" start-tag

In order to have a correct DTD validation you need to add a valid DOCTYPE at the beginning of the VoiceXML document, e.g. VoiceXML 2.1 DOCTYPE is the following:

`<!DOCTYPE vxml PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD VOICEXML 2.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/vxml.dtd">`.

Answer (score 0):

Voximal integrates a command line tool called vxmlvalidator.

If you install the Voximal package you can use it to validate VoiceXML 2.0 and 2.1 standard documents.

```
root@192:~# vxmlvalidator http://demo.ulex.fr/vxml/index.vxml
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.

VALID: http://demo.ulex.fr/vxml/index.vxml

TIME PROCESSING: 213697

PAGES PARSED: 1 (4.67952 p/s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are using scripting language or static vxml, you must run the page in browser to see what xml output you get.
It will tell you if any ecmascript/xml errors. 
Even if xml output is correct, then you have to check all tags carefully.

Sometimes vxml servers won't give you proper error information.